# How to refresh a table without clicking again on my button

Tags: php

For my school I have to make a club management with a table, so I have a menu to choose to show the table, I submit and I have my table, and I want to Order By my table, I did it with input, but to show the Order By that I've made, I have to click again on the button that shows the Table, do you know how to update this table without make this click again ?

```
if(isset($_POST['submitmenu'])){
     if($_POST['choix']=="inserer"){
     form_insert();
}

    if($_POST['choix']=="afficher"){
       afficher_equip();
    }  

    if($_POST['choix']=="supprimer"){
        suppr();
    }

     if($_POST['choix']=="match"){
        match();
     }
}

function afficher_equip(){
    $link = mysqli_connect("venus","aparent","","aparent");
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Equipe, Etat, Classement, Match_Joue, Victoire, Defaite, id FROM hockey_club ORDER BY Classement ASC");

    if(isset($_GET['sortaz'])){
        $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Equipe, Etat, Classement, Match_Joue, Victoire, Defaite, id FROM hockey_club ORDER BY Equipe ASC");
   }

echo "<table style='border-collapse: collapse;' class='tableau'>";

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Equipe</th>";
        echo "<th>Etat</th>";
        echo "<th>Classement</th>";
        echo "<th>Match joues</th>";
        echo "<th>Victoires</th>";
        echo "<th>Defaites</th>";
        echo "<th>ID</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>";

    while ($hockey_club = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

        foreach($hockey_club as $i => $valeur){
            echo "<td style='border: 2px solid black;  padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center; '>$valeur</td>";   
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table><br>";

    echo"<div class='buttonsort'>
    Il faut appuyer a nouveau sur Afficher le classement apres avoir choisi le Order By: a corriger
        <form method='GET' action=''>
        <input type='submit' class='sort' style='vertical-align:middle' name='sortaz' value='A-Z'/>
        <input type='submit' class='sort' style='vertical-align:middle' name='sortetat' value='Etat'/>
        <input type='submit' class='sort' style='vertical-align:middle' name='sortclassement' value='Classement'/>
        <input type='submit' class='sort' style='vertical-align:middle' name='sortmj' value='Match Joues'/>
        <input type='submit' class='sort' style='vertical-align:middle' name='sortvic' value='Victoires'/>
        <input type='submit' class='sort' style='vertical-align:middle' name='sortdef' value='Defaites'/>
        <input type='submit' class='sort' style='vertical-align:middle' name='sortid' value='ID'/></form></div>";  
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want better please? Let me see if I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're wanting to order a table by a certain metric and then refresh the table to view this change.

One thing you could do is, when the user selects a metric to order the table by, call the function which builds the table (the one that is called when a user clicks 'Show Table').

Doing it this way means you don't need to write much more code and you're reusing existing code, which is normally good practice.